# How to get the name of a higher order function in F#?

Tags: reflection, f#

```
let Sigmund () = 
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
let Donald () = 
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
let Eustachio () = 
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name

let get_name_of_x (x: unit -> unit) =
    //System.Reflection.???
    ()

let x = 
    [|
    Sigmund
    Donald
    Eustachio
    |]

x |> Array.iter (fun x -> x() |> printfn "%s") // prints all the names
```

Since the functions can see their own name, I know it should be possible to get the name of the function passed into `get_name_of_x`, but I can't figure out how. Having the ability to do this would be useful in writing my own testing library.

[Fuchu](https://github.com/mausch/Fuchu) for example does not strip names directly from functions, and using DUs for composition instead of functions makes it less flexible than it could be, so it might be worth improving on.

Comment: Depending on your exact use case, a possible solution since F# 4.0 is to use `[<ReflectedDefinition(true)>]` on the argument, see "Implicit quotation of method arguments" [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/04/29/rounding-out-visual-f-4-0-in-vs-2015-rc/).